# WP Bakery Visual Composer is not working w/ WP 5.0

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Just installed the WP 5.0 update and I have approximately 30+ client sites that have automatically installed this update and they all have WP Bakery as their site builder.

I need a way to disable the builder that comes built-in with this new version of WP as my clients are all familiar and prefer WP Bakery Visual Composer; not this new thing that appears to be forced on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution:

we need to install this plugin 
Classic Editor is available as an option instead of using new editor

https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/